# How to express a constraint in MOSEK

Tags: mosek

I have the following constraint to be implemented in Mosek, where the unknown variable is x.

[image]

I'm trying to follow the discussion [here](https://docs.mosek.com/latest/pythonfusion/case-studies-logistic.html#doc-case-studies-logistic). I could write the constraint as the intersection between 15 exponential cones and one half space. However, what is the best way to write the exponential cone in Mosek given that I have a linear combination of the elements of the unknown x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fusion API you write the constraint `t\geq exp(u)` as

```
M.constraint(Expr.hstack(t, Expr.constTerm(1.0), u), Domain.inPExpCone())
```

and `u` can be an expression constructed in a more complicated way, say

```
y1 = Expr.sub(Expr.dot(c1, x), b1)
u = Expr.mul(r, y1)
....
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks. How do I write the same with Mosek R?

Comment: The answer is in the manual: https://docs.mosek.com/latest/rmosek/index.html

Comment: In Rmosek you can also put a sequence of affine expressions in a cone https://docs.mosek.com/latest/rmosek/tutorial-affine-conic.html